# How to write test case using Jest for Yup.isValid function?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, yup

I am trying to add a unit test to validate the `Yup.isValid` function, but the after running test case showing error as: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`. Even if I am changing the minimum timeout of jasmine same error showing. My function to validate the Yup schema is:

```
export const validateSchema= (
  validationSchema,
  data
) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await validationSchema
      isValid(data)
      .then(isFormValid => {
        //passing response to method
      })
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
};
```

My test case is:

```
test("validate Schema",async () => {
    let catchFn = jest.fn();
    let data= someSampleData;
    //data is valid as per the schema
   await validationSchema(
        validationSchema,
        data
      )
      .then(res => {
       //My expected condition
      })
      .catch(catchFn);
  });
```

Above test case is not going to then where I can put my condition. Same error is coming as I mentioned. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How did you set a timeout? Did you check how long the promise takes to resolve? From what you posted, it's pending. That there's Jasmine in use suggests that you use old Jest version, newer versions don't depend on Jasmine. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @estus I dont think it is a versions issue.I increase the timeout by adding 9000 in test function like :   test("validate Schema",async () => {
  }, 9000);

Answer (score 4):

For large schemas it might be nice to use yup's validateAt api to pass in a path to validate for, so fixture data can be more concise.

Jest specs could look something like:

```
await expect(schema.validateAt(path, fixture)).rejects.toBeTruthy()
```

```
  it("requires person's name", async () => {
    await expect(schema.validateAt('person.name', {})).rejects.toBeFalsy()
    await expect(schema.validateAt('person.name', {person: {name: "something"}})).resolves.toBeTruthy()

  }
```

Unit testing yup is interesting, in that a lot of it is configuration, testing that libraries work the way they say they do can be extraneous. However, this does seem to helpful for testing more complex custom schema validation behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

`validateSchema` uses promise construction antipattern and shows one of the reasons why it's considered an antipattern, `new Promise` is unneeded construction that is prone to human errors.

The use of `async` as `Promise` executor is a mistake that contributes to the antipattern. `Promise` executor ignores a promise that is returned from `async` function.  `resolve` is never called, while `.catch(error => reject(error))` is no-op. `validateSchema` returns either rejected or pending promise. If pending promise is returned from a test, this results in a timeout.

It should be:

```
export const validateSchema= async (
  validationSchema,
  data
) => {
    await validationSchema;
    const isFormValid = isValid(data);
    await updateFormValidFlag(isFormValid, theFormName); // does it return a promise?
  });
};
```

Mixing `await` and raw promises is rarely ever needed. Using dummy function in `catch` in test will result in supressing errors, which is rarely a desirable behaviour.

The test can be:

```
test("validate Schema",async () => {
   let data= someSampleData;
   await validateSchema(...);
   //My expected condition
});
```

Comment: isFormValid  is always returning false in test case

Comment: Reasons why this could happen aren't covered in the question. As for timeout problem, that's the explanation.

Comment: yeah you are correct, but removing promises from the method is not going to solve our problem,still we are not able to test the test cases for the yup.isValid function that is mentioned in the question title.

Comment: It's unknown why there's a problem with isValid. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you provide data that isn't valid then it will return false. There's no data and no schema in the question. `updateFormValidFlag` isn't shown. Also notice that there's `await validationSchema(`. Is it a typo, shouldn't it be `await validateSchema(`?

Answer (score 1):

Just another example, I am mainly check for true values

```
it( 'should handle validating object', async () => {
  const result = await schema.isValid(myObject)
  expect( result ).toEqual( true )
} )
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this won't provide verbose feedback on which rule it explicitly failed.

Answer (score 0):

We use `schema.validate()` method in combination with promise assertion:

```
describe('Standing order form validations', () => {
    it('passes when required form values are valid', async () => {
        const schema = getValidationSchema();

        const result = schema.validate({
            receiver: { iban: 'AT352011142012679110' },
            nextExecutionDate: getTomorrow(),
            executionInterval: EXECUTION_INTERVAL.MONTHLY,
            amount: { value: 100, precision: 2, currency: 'EUR' },
        });

        await expect(result).resolves.toBeTruthy();
    });

    ...
```

This provides verbose feedback on which rule it explicitly failed:

[image: Example of an error when YUP schema failed]

It helps to understand why the schema fails really quick.